# allocating null pointer when passed to function

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference

This program contains a typical node struct for a linked list (so a pointer to the next node and an int containing a value). I have the following test functions:

```
void F(NODE** Y, int value)
{
    NODE* X = *Y;

    if(!X)
    {
        printf("case1...\n");
        X = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        X->Data = value;
        return;
    }
    printf("case2...\n");
    X->Next = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    X->Next->Data = value;
    return;
}

void myPrint(NODE** Y)
{
    NODE* X = *Y;
    printf("printing...\n");

    printf("%d %d\n", X->Data, X->Next->Data);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    NODE* n = NULL;

    F(&n, 5);
    F(&n, 10);

    myPrint(&n);
}
```

This code produces the following output in Linux:

```
case1...
case1...
printing...
Segmentation fault
```

I don't understand why passing a null pointer to the function will always cause the first case to occur. It seems like the pointer is being passed by value, but I don't think that's what's going on. If I call `malloc()` on the node inside of `main()` and then pass it to `F()`, the second case will be hit but never the first. This at least makes partial sense to me, since the node will never be null when it is passed to `F()` from `main()`, but obviously allocating the node before passing it to `F()` means that the null check inside `F()` will never be true.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Is there a way to pass `n` to `F()` while it's null and have it behave the way I want it to? Or do I have to allocate `n` outside of `F()` and remove the null check inside of `F()`?

Comment: The names of functions should be meaningful within the context of what the function does.   Usually this means the function name has an active verb (usually as the first part of the function name) I.E. getValue() calcResult(), etc.   So this function: `F()`  is rather meaningless.  and even after I read the function, I was not sure what the function was expected to do.

Comment: When calling the function: `malloc()` and family of functions,  1) do not cast the returned value because in C, it is a `void *` so can be assigned to any pointer and casting just clutters the code and makes maintenance more difficult.  2) the function: `malloc()` and family of functions can fail.  So always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful otherwise, a failure will cause the code to be referencing address 0x0000000000 which will result in undefined behaviour and cause a seg fault event

Comment: Your fundamental problem is that you don't understand that `X` is not an alias for `n`.  `*Y` is an alias for `n`. When you assign `*Y` to `X` you are assigning the value of `n` to `X`, not making `X` an alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After allocation for `X` you need to set it in `*Y` in the function `F()`. Otherwise, it does not get reflected once `F()` returns.

So I would change code to

```
void F(NODE** Y, int value)
{
    NODE* X = *Y;

    if(!X)
    {
        printf("case1...\n");
        X = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        X->Data = value;

        *Y = X;  //set the allocated pointer
        return;
    }
    printf("case2...\n");
    X->Next = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    X->Next->Data = value;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much, this was driving me insane. It was literally making me question everything I had learned in school.

Answer (score 0):

In the function `F()` when the 'n' in main() contains NULL;

the code is not setting the contents of 'n' to point to the malloc'd memory.

Changing the value contained in the local variable 'X' has no effect on the 'n' in main()